# TabLayout tabItem tabGravity center not working

Tags: android, xml, android-tablayout

It's working fine for more than 5 tabs but when 3 tabs looking not so good.
This is my TabLayout XML Code:

```
 <android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
            android:gravity="center"
            android:id="@+id/tabs"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@+id/search_bar"
            android:fillViewport="false"
            app:tabGravity="center"
            app:tabIndicatorColor="@color/ThemeColor"
            app:tabIndicatorHeight="6dp"
            app:tabMode="scrollable"
            android:paddingBottom="2dp"
            android:background="@drawable/bottom_dotted_border"
            app:tabSelectedTextColor="@color/ThemeColor"
            app:tabTextAppearance="@style/TabLayoutTextStyle"
            app:tabTextColor="@color/White" />
```

[problamatic tab](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XVP2h.png)
[desire tab](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZDfQU.png)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43588653/tablayout-gravity-center-is-not-working

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30843775/tab-not-taking-full-width-on-tablet-device-using-android-support-design-widget/39018131#39018131

Comment: This solution is not correct cause I want to fill the width with the added item of the tab .

Comment: @MdAslamHossin your tab title is dynamic or fixed

Answer (score 1):

**just change  this** `app:tabMode="scrollable"` **to** `app:tabMode="fixed"` **in youor tab layout**

> **1. app:tabMode="fixed** : the tabs are fixed in your tab layout (its not good for when your tabs have long  tabtitles)
>
> **2. tabMode:scrollable** - you can scroll your tabs horizontally when your tabs have long  tabtitles

**sample code**

```
<android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
        android:gravity="center"
        android:id="@+id/tabs"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/search_bar"
        android:fillViewport="false"
        app:tabGravity="fill"
        app:tabMode="fixed"
        app:tabIndicatorColor="@color/ThemeColor"
        app:tabIndicatorHeight="6dp"
        android:paddingBottom="2dp"
        android:background="@drawable/bottom_dotted_border"
        app:tabSelectedTextColor="@color/ThemeColor"
        app:tabTextAppearance="@style/TabLayoutTextStyle"
        app:tabTextColor="@color/White" />
```

Comment: app:tabMode="fixed"  will cut off long string for tab title.

Comment: Any solution ?? kindly help me.

Comment: @MdAslamHossin  check updated ans use `app:tabGravity="fill"`

Answer (score 0):

If you use `tabMode:scrollable` just fix the `android:layout_width="match_parent"` to `"wrap_content"`